# Why does my ubuntu system keep loging me out after i try to open an app

Tags: 22.04, crash, .desktop, logout

If i try to open firefox or spotify or any other app that is bigger ,the screen goes black and it log me out . I tried apt update and upgrade , ceating a new profile. Yesterday everything was fine , i haven t updated it since yesterday and today when i tried to open fiferox it logged me out

Comment: "*it logged me out*" is likely a *desktop crash*. Check /var/crash to read the crash file. Also check your logs around the time of the crash.

Comment: yeah, i looked at the crash files but i see only 4 files and idk how to read them exactly because my pc crash everytime i open an app and it s like an infinite loop , i also looke at the journalctl systemd-oomd and i see that the oom kill the procceses but i made another swapfile which has 4gb free

Comment: 16 GB and another weird thing is that my virtual machine with kali works , i use gnome box

Comment: yeah , i added swap but i still have the problem. i used free and on swap used it is 0

Comment: yes , acutally i found out it s not the oom killer for sure but now i don t know what else can it be

Comment: Please add new information by revising and improving your question above. Don't comment on your own question. Comments are how we prompt you to add more information until your question is answerable (currently it's not answerable). If you don't know how to read .crash files, then look up how.

Comment: Thank you for your help ♥️

Comment: Any solution? I seem to have the same issue. It arose suddenly. One day it worked, the next day it did not anymore. However it seems to apps which use chromium run time under the hood (like electron.js)